# Why can't I release an object anymore?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

After I updated to Xcode 4.2, I can no longer release anything.
When I start typing "release" it suggest "release" but with a red line across.

If I write it anyway it shows an error and displays these two messages:

'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
Automatic Reference Counting forbids explicit message send of 'release'

Does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to turn off [Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). You do this by clicking on your project in the navigator (the top item in the finder-like thing on the left), then click on your target, select *"Build Settings"* and turn off the option *"Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting"* (you can use the search field on the upper right to search it).

Another possibility is to [migrate your project to ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368600/some-questions-about-automatic-reference-counting-in-ios5-sdk/6368692#6368692).

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. You really made my day :D... I was stuck in learning to program to the iPhone but now I can continue :D

Comment: The search probably won't work as expected. The flag is called CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC in user defined section. Or remember to uncheck "Automatic Reference Counting" when creating new projects.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks...
its CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC .. you need to make it NO available under Build Setting. Actually I got this error after updating to Cordova from Phonegap. I hope I wont get into more troubles by doing so.. Cheers.. Happy Coding!!