# IOS: automatic reference counting

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I have a question: If I created an app with ARC, what's the last version IOS compatible for my app? If I upload my app in AppStore, everyone can use my app? or only people with a device with a specific ios version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some questions about Automatic Reference Counting in iOS5 SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368600/some-questions-about-automatic-reference-counting-in-ios5-sdk)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ARC is supported on iOS 4.0 with one caveat: automatic nulling of weak references is only supported on iOS 5.0 and above.

Comment: The caveat is weak references. From: @rpetrich If only using weak references for additional safety, manually call the new runtime functions if they're available and fallback to simple assignment on __unsafe_unretained variables if not.

Answer (score 2):

ARC compiled applications work on devices with iOS 4 or better.

Comment: then if I done an app for iPad there aren't problems because it's possible to update the device at ios 4 or better, no?

Comment: Original iPads came with iOS 3.2. You may run into users with an original iPad not yet updated. That said, we have been targetting iOS 4 or better in our latest projects (last 6 months)

Answer (score 0):

ARC "magic" is done by the compiler, so it is safe to use with iOS 4 of newer. In fact, iOS 4+ is a supported target for ARC applications. Here's a link with more information about ARC: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html