# release method deprecated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

When has happen to the release method? I always release a memory allocation when I am done with it and now it seems that the method has been deprecated. Or maybe it does not work for some objects?

Anyway, this is what I did:

```
Customer *aCustomer = [[Customer alloc] init];
...
[aCustomer release];
```

and I get an error there... Anyone care to explain why I get an error now that I release my memory? The error message is:

> 'release' in unavailable: not available in automatic reference
>   counting mode ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'

Comment: With ARC the compiler takes care of retain counts so you don't have to, in fact aren't allowed to.

Comment: That's why its being deprecated!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have enabled the 'ARC', then you don't need to `release` an object. That will be handled by the compiler. `retain`, `release` and `autorelease` are all handled by the compiler.

**Edit:**
You could know more about that from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1)

Also there already a SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368600/some-questions-about-automatic-reference-counting-in-ios5-sdk) exists. Please go thru that.

Comment: Ah, I see... Didn't know that. So I don't really need to use the retain method so often now do I? Do you know where I can read up on this?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks guys for all the effort you have put in :)

Answer (score 1):

To manage memory by yourself go to "build settings" and set the flag "Objective-C automatic reference counting" to "No" (it's under "Apple LLVM compiler")

Answer (score 1):

> Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) for Objective-C makes memory
>   management the job of the compiler. By enabling ARC with the new Apple
>   LLVM compiler, you will never need to type retain or release again,
>   dramatically simplifying the development process, while reducing
>   crashes and memory leaks. The compiler has a complete understanding of
>   your objects, and releases each object the instant it is no longer
>   used, so apps run as fast as ever, with predictable, smooth
>   performance.

[- iOS 5 for Developers](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/)

Consider using ARC (Automatic Retain Counting) for your project. There is a refactoring that will convert a current project.