# In XCode 4.3.2, when I run the ARC conversion refactor tool, all of my property options that were "retain" are NOT being changed into "strong"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, refactoring, automatic-ref-counting

In XCode 4.3.2, when I run the ARC conversion refactor tool, all of my property options that were "retain" are NOT being changed into "strong".  Is "strong" implied now or is this just a problem with XCode 4.3.2?

Example:

Before

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * someString;
```

After

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString * someString;
```

Comment: See earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796476/property-definitions-with-arc-strong-or-retain

Comment: `retain` is still valid AFAIK, but it does seem like it should get converted.

Comment: thanks guys, I was unclear in my question (see edits above).  It's just removing the "retain" option without adding in "strong", which ends up being a compiler warning, and not running.  It's doing this on all 5 of my projects.

Comment: strong is the default if the attribute is not given

Comment: @Phix: No, for properties the default is `assign`. `__strong` is the default memory qualifier for _variables_.

Comment: Whoa, it's doing _what_?! That completely changes the meaning!

Comment: Just do a replace thing (that looks like find) and replace all?....

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927727/objective-c-arc-strong-vs-retain-and-weak-vs-assign

Comment: @Josh Caswell retain is actually not valid in ARC

Comment: @joseph.hainline Erlend Boe's answer is correct. The output after running the tool only includes `(nonatomic)` because `strong` is the default, so the output is the same as `(nonatomic, strong)`.

Comment: @qegal: That's not true. `retain` on a property is accepted by Apple/LLVM 3.1, and it is explicitly listed in [Clang's ARC doc](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property). Also note that properties defaulting to `strong` is a _change_, and a big one, that occurred in 3.1.

Comment: @josh caswell Check out this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061162/release-method-deprecated>

Comment: @qegal: What? That question is about the `release` _method_ (and, peripherally, the `retain` method), not the property ownership qualifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"strong" is the default when using ARC (LLVM 3.1), so the new code is correct.
(before ARC, the default was "assign")
See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property

Answer (score 0):

Strong is the equivalent of the non-ARC retain. So when you shift from non-ARC to ARC XCode doesn't understand the word retain and hence removes it. Thereby causing an error or atleast a warning, as all the instance variables require atleast two properties declared.

Comment: Retain is not **rejected** by Xcode in that sense of the word. It will still operate. It's just that retain is now depreciated.