# iOS and ARC management

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, reference-counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [release method deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061162/release-method-deprecated)

I have this code

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:yourURL];
```

Do I need to release it if my project is using ARC? What should I look for to prevent unnecessary leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release method is no longer relevant with ARC.  If you want to read more about ARC check out [this handy article.](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html)

If you're still concerned about leaks ([they *can* still happen](https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/memory-leaks-with-arc/)), you can click and hold on the "run" arrow at the top left of the XCode window, select "Profile," and run.  This will open up the Instruments app.  From there, you can select the "Leaks" module which will show you any leaks it finds in your program as it runs.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

How many times will this be asked per day? NO, you don't have to release it. The object is managed by ARC. For more info, [read this doc link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)