# How Releas in stance in ARC mode

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting

i need some guide lines for this. i want to relase an instance immediatly in ARC mode
Is this the correct way to do it

> ```
> if(secondScreenAudio.isPlaying == true){
>     [secondScreenAudio stop];
>     @autoreleasepool {
>        secondScreenAudio = nil; 
>     }
> }
> ```

plz provide some tips 
thanks

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061162/release-method-deprecated

Comment: i like to set to nil in dealloc. But remember, you cannot call [super dealloc]

Comment: Use `secondScreenAudio = nil;` without `@autorelease` block

Comment: take a look with doc apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

thats correct... you dont have to put @autorelease tho..  and you dont use autorelease that way either... if u set it to nil.. and no other hard references are pointing to the object.. it will be released.